# Non-Greedy regex acts greedy based on the position of atoms in regex

Tags: regex, tcl, non-greedy

I came across one situation where I wanted to use non-greedy atom `.*?` in the regex pattern.

```
set input "Device ID: HOST1
Interface: GigabitEthernet0/1,  Port ID (outgoing port): GigabitEthernet2/43
Device ID: HOST2
Entry address(es):
Interface: GigabitEthernet0/2,  Port ID (outgoing port): GigabitEthernet2/43
"

puts "======== Non-Greedy regex starting with some other patterns ========"
puts [ regexp -inline {Device\s+ID:.*?outgoing\s+port\):\s+} $input]
puts "======== Non-Greedy regex at first ========"
puts [ regexp -inline {.*?outgoing\s+port\):\s+} $input]
```

**Output :**

```
======== Non-Greedy regex starting with some other patterns ========
{Device ID: HOST1
Interface: GigabitEthernet0/1,  Port ID (outgoing port): GigabitEthernet2/43
Device ID: HOST2
Entry address(es):
Interface: GigabitEthernet0/2,  Port ID (outgoing port): }
======== Non-Greedy regex at first ========
{Device ID: HOST1
Interface: GigabitEthernet0/1,  Port ID (outgoing port): }
```

While `.*?outgoing\s+port\):\s+` is matching till the first occurrence, the pattern `Device\s+ID:.*?outgoing\s+port\):\s+` is not stopping at the first occurrence of the match.

Why the behavior of non-greedy match is getting affected due to placement of the atoms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not that well documented (IMO) but [the re_syntax man page](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm#M95) says this about greedy/non-greedy preference:

> A branch has the same preference as the **first** quantified atom in it which has a preference.

(emphasis mine)

So if you have `.*` as the first quantifier, the whole RE will be greedy,
and if you have `.*?` as the first quantifier, the whole RE will be non-greedy.

Comment: Oh, great catch, re-read it for my memory while answering but didn't catch the first operator is greedy in `Device\s+...`. so if I undertsood well, changing the first `\s+` to `\s+?`  should do ?

Comment: @Tensibai & @glenn : Yes!. With `Device\s+?ID:.*?outgoing\s+port\):\s+` it is matching only up to the first occurrence. This is great. Thanks to Mr.Glenn!!!